# Why does TextMate use a different highlighting for the HTML <style> tag?

Tags: themes, textmate

I wonder why TextMate has a different highlighting for the HTML  Tag. As you can see in the screenshot, the angle brackets are white. The others are not. It doesn't matter which theme i use. It's always highlighted different.

Is it a bug or can i fix it in the Theme?

Thanks. :)

[image: Screenshot of TextMate showing different tag highlighting.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textmate support embedded CSS and Javascript syntax highlighting for HTML files.

Whenever it sees the style or script tag it changes the scope to CSS (or Javasript) to give you proper syntax highlighting. that's why the color of style tag and script tags (without SRC attribute) are different. they get their coloring from the CSS or Javascript part of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

The scope for these symbols is `source.css.embedded.html punctuation.definition.tag.html`, so you can add a new element to theme with the desired color, or add this scope to the existing one, I did this in my theme like this:

[image: Added scope]